# Constructing a map between tensor product of vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products

For a given vector space $V$ over $\mathbb{C}$, is there a non-zero map (with kernel isomorphic to $\mathbb{C})$

$$\phi\colon V\otimes\bigwedge\nolimits^2V\longrightarrow \mathrm{Sym}^2 V\otimes\mathrm{Sym}^2(\bigwedge\nolimits^2 V)$$ such that the composition $\psi\circ\phi$ is zero, where $\psi\colon \mathrm{Sym}^2 V\otimes\mathrm{Sym}^2(\bigwedge\nolimits^2 V)\to \mathrm{Sym}^3(\mathrm{Sym}^2V)$ is given by $\psi ((s\cdot t)\otimes (u\wedge v)\cdot(w\wedge z))=((u\cdot w)\cdot(v\cdot z)-(u\cdot z)\cdot(v\cdot w))\cdot (s\cdot t)$.

My first guess was that $\phi (u\otimes (v\wedge w))=(u\cdot u)\otimes ((v\wedge w)\cdot (v\wedge w))$ but I don't think this works.

Comment: Have you tried to determine the dimension of the kernel of $\psi$ (when $V$ is finite dimensional)?

Comment: Also, is there a reason you're using $\cdot$ for the symmetric product as opposed to $\vee$?

Comment: Yes, but I am not sure. If $(uw)(vz)-(uz)(vw)=0$ what can we say? It seems $w$ should be a scalar multiple of $z$? Is that correct, in that case kernel is zero (which is not what i am looking for).

Comment: A small edit, I want $\phi$ to have kernel $\mathbb{C}$ (not injective). Sorry for the typo before.

Comment: What do you mean when the kernel is $\Bbb C$? How is $\Bbb C$ a subspace of $V \otimes \wedge^2 V$?

Comment: I mean isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$, i.e. kernel is one dimensional.

Comment: Oh, good.${}{}{}{}$